# Get Album's cover photo

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Facebook Graph Api to get the photo album's cover photo using the resource graph.facebook.com/**cover_photo**/picture where **cover_photo** is the id of the photo from the album object. However, doing this with or without a token gives me either https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v1/yC/r/gtEJuZGrBLG.jpg  or https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yA/r/gPCjrIGykBe.gif I'm not sure why though as I have the proper permissions to access the user's albums in the 1st place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just use

```
/album_id/picture
```

This should give you the cover photo according to the docs

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/#connections

You need a valid access_token of course

Comment: So if I paste this url into the browser's address bar, I should get the cover_photo?
https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/album.php?fbid=244664205701523&id=100004738355529&aid=1073741828/picture

But it doesn't work!

Comment: You need a valid access_token as stated above